# Find a word before one of two possible separators

Tags: regex, r

```
word:12335
anotherword:2323434
totallydifferentword/455
word/32
```

I need to grab the character string before the `:` or `/` using only base R functions. I can do this using `stringr` but don't want to add another dependency to my package. The words can have variable number of character but would always end at (one of) the separator(s). I don't need to keep what comes after.

Comment: Are the characters always alpha a-z? Or can they be any characters? With regex questions, try to provide as many details as possible. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: yes, always alpha although the case might be mixed. `WoRd`.

Comment: if cases are mixed you may want `[a-zA-z]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
x <- c("word:12335", "anotherword:2323434", "totallydifferentword/455", "word/32")
lapply(strsplit(x, ":|/"), function(z) z[[1]]) #as a list
sapply(strsplit(x, ":|/"), function(z) z[[1]]) #as a string
```

There are regex solutions with `gsub` that will work too but in my experiences with similar problems `strsplit` will be less eloquent but faster.

I supose this regex would work as well:

```
gsub("([a-z]+)([/|:])([0-9]+)", "\\1", x)
```

In this case gsub was faster:

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr    min     lq median     uq     max
1     GSUB() 19.127 21.460 22.392 23.792 106.362
2 STRSPLIT() 46.650 50.849 53.182 54.581 854.162
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could use use a choice of separators in `strsplit`. Thanks Tyler!

Comment: You can use any regex expression.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick in Ruby
 http://rubular.com/r/PzVQVIpKPq

```
^(\w+)(?:[:\/])
```

Starting from the front of the string, grab any word characters and capture them, until you reach the non-capturing `/` or `:`

Answer (score 0):

[This regex seems to work](http://rubular.com/r/Prp6NgnToB). Can you use that in R?

Comment: It's a good idea to always include code in your answer, as there is no guarantee that the link you've provided will be there in the future. (By all means leave the link as well as having the code)

Comment: It's rather a kewl link. Entitled "Rubular" it has an input box and produces the results of regex expressions (at least whatever this versioon of Ruby uses). Have never seen a similar page driven by the R-regex engine, but such  destination might be useful. (I generally just test at the R-console.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package *unglue* :

```r
library(unglue)
x <- c("word:12335", "anotherword:2323434", "totallydifferentword/455", "word/32")
unglue_vec(x, "{res}{=[:/].*?}")
#> [1] "word"                 "anotherword"          "totallydifferentword"
#> [4] "word"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- `{res}` matches anything and will be returned, it's equivalent to `{res=.*?}`
- `{=[:/].*?}` matches anything starting with `:` or `/` and won't be returned as we have no lhs to `=`